# display chinese character in eclipse console output

Tags: eclipse, encoding, console, cjk

I am trying to display some Chinese characters in the GB2312 encoding in the eclipse console.  I realize that in Run Dialog -> Common tab -> Console Encoding, I can choose additional encodings other than the default CP1252.  However, how I can add additional encodings, like GB2312?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.dltk/msg00405.html):

> Since [3.4 (Ganymede)](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/common.htm), the default encoding is inherited from the resource (project) associated with the launch configuration.
>   If encoding is not specified for the project - encoding configured for the workspace or system default encoding is used.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/images/launchers/launcher_eclipse_common.png))</sub>

Since it appears you cannot change console encoding anywhere else but in the Run configuration's common tab (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg79804.html)), I am not sure it can be done at this point.
That already has some side effect like [bug 238945](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238945).

As illustrated by [this article](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/eclipse/eclipse_quickguide_display_unicode_in_console.html), you can only change the encoding once.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer to this question is explained here:
http://ovesh.limon100.com/blog/2009/03/24/eclipse-console-encoding-external-tools/

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Now I am able to output chinese characters in the eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

To display Chinese or any Asia Characters, you may want to set the encoding to UTF-8 .

This answer helped me and may also help you: [Eclipse Encoding MacRoman -> UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707986/eclipse-encoding-macroman-utf8)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem because Chinese characters were appearing as ?s in the console output.
In my case the code was running in Tomcat.

I fixed the problem as follows Top Menu > Run > Run Configurations... > Tomcat vX.X Server at localhost > Common tab > Encoding > Other UTF-8

Restart the server if it was already running.