# Eclipse Encoding MacRoman -> UTF8

Tags: eclipse, encoding, editor

I recently created a project, organized it and well... I used my Mac with Eclipse running. Somehow it stored everything in MacRoman. The project has to be UTF8. 
Is there any easy way to handle the conversions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have some detailed explanation in this [blog post](http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Setting+the+default+text+encoding+for+Eclipse) by [David HOLT](http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/~dholt) for the [WOLips/WOProject](http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/WOL/Home).

Check your default preferences:

[image: Encoding in Eclipse preferences]

> In Eclipse, go to `Preferences>General>Workspace` and select `UTF-8` as the `Text File Encoding`.
>   This should set the encoding for all the resources in your workspace. Any components you create from now on using the default encoding should all match.
>
> **Change the encoding for a resource (project, folder or file)**
>
> Right (or Control) click on the resource in the WO Package Explorer and select the Properties option at the bottom of the contextual menu.
>   Go to `Resource>Text File Encoding`.
>   You should see "`Inherited from container (UTF-8)`" if you've made the change above, otherwise it will be (MacRoman).
>   Select `Other - UTF-8` and Apply to make the warning go away.

Comment: Is there a way to change the text encoding for a large number of resources without going through them one by one?

Comment: @JDelage By default they should all be set to "Inherited from container". The containers up to the project should be like that, and the project should be set to the default. So when you change the default, it applies recursively. Not sure if it attempts to re-encode things… it's all pretty bizarre

Comment: This just changes the encoding for new files. Do I have to manually convert every old file to the new encoding. In Spanish there are a lot of characters that get messed up.

Comment: I've had this problem today (2016-04-07) and after I'd changed the encoding on new resources, I still had wrong characters in my console. The solution for me was to Clean my project (Project > Clean...) in Eclipse. After that, rebuild and all was good.