# appengine and jinja2 templating, correctly handling encoding for latin charset

Tags: google-app-engine, character-encoding, jinja2

I'm building a simple hierarchical template with jinja.
I was splitting my monolithic html file in smaller chunks to reuse them. 
In my html I had accented characters like èàù...
when I tried to run the app I received errors complaining about  my files not beeing properly encoded.
So I decided to adhere to utf-8 standars and substituted those characters with things like `&ugrave;` 
and so on...
This worked but is seems a bit cumbersome as a workflow.
I'm wandering which is the correct approach to this kind of problems both with template files and content that have to be rendered in those templates.

I suppose that it is good practice to encode texts in utf-8 before storing them but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use utf-8 in your (html) files, templates and python code it works fine and you can use : èàù...

Make sure your editors use utf-8 encoded files are read this article about utf-8. : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python. You also can use :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

at the start of your Python modules.

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807748/when-to-use-utf8-as-a-header-in-py-files/13807795#13807795

Answer (score 0):

In templates, it is sufficient to save the file with correct utf-8 encoding, see image below.
For what concerns strings that you want to store in source code and pass around in your program, if you only need a quick and dirty suggestion, here it is:

1. save your .py files as utf-8
2. now you can use all characters you want in your strings
3. you only need explicitly inform the rest of the system that you are
   using an utf-8 encode

[image]

EXAMPLE

```
my_string = """I write àny character I want herè, just only ensurè that the encoding for the file you are writing is utf-8 àèàééàà"""

def utf8(s):
    return unicode(s, 'utf8')

pass_string_around = utf8(my_string)
```