# the project was not build since the source file could not be read

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to build an open source android project, but just after build starts, I get this error:

The project was not built since the source file   `/android/build/tools/droiddoc/test/generics/src/com/android/generics/TestComparable.java`
could not be read

I tried everything I found, **Refresh > Clean > build / Restart > refresh > Clean > build**.

I understand it could be an encoding problem since that file may come from a repository, and was stored on windows or something.

If you know a solution or a possible solution, please help, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Can you open that file in a text editor?

Comment: What build tools are you using? and IDE?

Comment: I am using eclipse, and yes I can open that file both in eclipse and editor. I may want to add that I am using eclipse Indigo, and ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The most common cause is an incompatible encoding in the file. I get
these some times on linux when I get a file with cp1252 (or whatever the
window encoding is)".

Try setting your eclipse's encoding to [utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2708219/1903960).

Comment: @sica09 i think you should accept the answer too so question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I have opened the Project > Properties > Resources > Linked Resources and deleted the resources with error marks, since these links were broken anyway. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a different solution than mentioned here.

I was doing a no-no, I imported a project that had a .project file, and there was some errors in the way my version of eclipse was reading some of the files. The package names and files had a little ! symbol with a yellow background.

The solution was to delete the packages. Obviously make a backup. But in doing this most times the files nor the packages were deleted. Instead eclipse refreshed and the desired files were there. Sometimes I had to hit refresh (F5), and sometimes I had to restore files.

I found it best to delete the packages as that is where eclipse was having reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Clean... worked for me when a deleted file was not found.

Comment: Add it as comment to question