# Eclipse eGit not supporting danish letters æøå (utf-8)?

Tags: eclipse, git, utf-8, github, egit

Im using eclipse and eGit to commit my java codes.

But when i commit Strings(or whatever) with æ,ø or å it changes to special char on Github.
This is a problem, because when i pull, it returns those special chars!

Can i force git/eGit/Github to use æ,ø and å. 
I'm guessing the encryption is not utf-8?

Problem is on both Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu).
It happens when i push to github (through eclipse and eGit and also same problem via command-line). Ø is changed to a ? sign.
Here is how it looks in eclipse:

```
Element str = doc.createElement("Størrelse");
```

and here is how it will look on github

```
Element str = doc.createElement("St�rrelse");
```

When i then pull from github i will get this:

```
Element str = doc.createElement("StÃ¸rrelse");
```

Can i force github to encode with UTF-8, or fix the encoding problem anyother way?

Comment: Do you use UTF-8 characters in the file names, commit messages and/or file contents? Does it work with the git command line client? Which platform? Windows/Linux/Mac?

Comment: Same problem on both Linux and Windows.
Yes UTF-8 characters in file names, commit messages and file contents.
Gonna test with command line in a second.

Comment: Command-line has the same problem:

This is how it looks on github. The question mark sign is a ø in eclipse.
Element str = doc.createElement("Stoerrelse");
+      Element str = doc.createElement("St�rrelse");

Comment: what OS are you running? And where do you have those problems? File names, commit messages or file content?

Comment: Both on Linux and Windows. Problem is in the file content.
As my other comment shows: when pushed to github ø is changed to ?.
And when i pull from github, i will get some gibberish  like "Ã¸" instead of "ø".

Comment: I tried to commit your line to my github repo and it works as expected using Linux and vim and command line git. So my guess would be that Eclipse messed up. Check your default encoding settings and the encoding of the file where it happens.

Comment: @nif I tried the same with command-line on windows, but had the same problem. What default encoding settings, for .java files? for eclipse? git?, github?

Comment: Default setting in eclipse is probably whatever the default setting in system is and Windows don't use utf-8 in system, so the setting will be the legacy charset there. In Linux in modern installation it should be utf-8, but if you have old upgraded installation it might not be.

Comment: @HjalteJ.: It depends on the editor you use, for Eclipse see [Eclipse encoding settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707986/eclipse-encoding-macroman-utf8). Per default, Eclipse uses the system encoding. You should never rely on that and set the encoding to UTF-8. Then you should convert any files in the wrong encoding to UTF-8 and force everybody to use the same settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git treats files as streams of bytes. It is not changing content of your files and does not care how they are encoded.

It also treats file names as streams of bytes (which breaks on macos which normalizes filenames, to decomposed normal form, so there are some workarounds there). It is not changing your file names either.

The problem is in how the files are written by Eclipse, how they are displayed on github and how it is displayed on the other installation of Eclipse. Make sure you have utf-8 encoding set in eclipse on both computers.

That said git there actually is a way to make git modify the files when it checks them in and out, but beyond converting newlines (which the Windows installer will offer you to turn on and I strongly suggest not doing that) you'd have to set up so called "clean" and "smudge" filters and if you didn't do that, git is not touching content of your files.

Comment: The problem was that one of the computers using Eclipse on windows, didnt have utf-8 encoding. So now its time to find all the utf-8 only characters, ugh.  Thanks, this answer made me understand how to fix the problem and why.

Answer (score 2):

This is 100% not a git issue. Git does not touch the encoding of your files in any way.

This could be a GitHub *display* issue (note: GitHub will never change the contents of your repo, so also not any encodings). But since you are also having the problem on your clients, GitHub is probably not at fault here.

The problem is probably caused by your editor. Your file content seems to be encoded as UTF-8 on write, but the editor you use to opening the files assumes it’s latin-1. Try checking your editor settings.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "at github" you think of viewing files through their web interface and that files are ok in a new clone to your local file system

This just mean that you and github disagree about the encoding of your files and is a very common (but subtle) cause of problems across platforms.

I would recommend that you:

- Avoid using anything but normal ASCII in *filenames*.
- Use the \uXXXX syntax for non-ASCII characters in your Java source.

Learning to do this now, will most likely save you a lot of problems later on.

Comment: I have edited my question, to hopefully clarify the problem better.
As i understand your message, there is no way to force encoding on github?
Also i already use only ASCII chararcters in filenames.
And could you clarify on \uXXXX syntax for non-ASCii characters?

Comment: I definitely disagree with this advice. Everything understands unicode these days and in Java it is even specified. Setting correct encoding should be all that is needed.

Comment: @janhudec feel free. It is my experience that things tend to break when you do stuff not tested by the original programmers.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: In Java, unicode literals are definitely tested and so they are in perl, python etc. I've been using them in several languages for years without single problem. The only language where I have problem is C++ with Microsoft compiler which insists on converting them to legacy charset and does not let you configure it, so there I have to use escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the meta, that worked perfectly on end. I know, this question is answered but that was not the exactly what you wanted to know so I thought I showed post this as well so that others can use it.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: It would improve the answer if you'd add where this should be added.