# Eclipse import project cvs shows accents with question marks

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, assembla

I've import a project from SVN (Assembla) in Eclipse Kepler. 
When the project is imported, the accented characters found in the code, appear with a question mark. I've changed workspace text encoding to UTF-8 and imported the project again, but the quiestion marks are still there.
I'm running eclipse on MAC. In windows, the importation works well.

Comment: did you follow the comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707986/eclipse-encoding-macroman-utf8 ? - perhaps you did it per resource instead of for the text files in the entire workspace?

Comment: @Michael. Yes i did it. And now Proyect->Properties->Resource says UTF-8, because I've changed it. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK on OS X - you might be getting hit with the specific file encoding, often there are magic comments at the top of the file or the file itself is set to an encoding.  You can alter your file encoding on Mac OS X like so:

> iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 File.txt > File.txt.utf8

And for a bunch of files:

```
find /path/to/Workspace -name \*.txt -type f | \
  (while read file; do
  iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "${file%.txt}.utf8";
  done);
```

This will convert all txt files, change *.txt to get different file types.

Comment: Great knowledge. I'm still novice in OS X. Thanx a lot.

Comment: Was that the problem, I only ask because it would help others to know that this was the ultimate fix for the encoding issues on Mac OS X and eclipse?