# Weird character set in white spaces

Tags: macos, encoding, utf-8

I am having an issue with char set on my mac and these characters show up differently on XQuartz and terminal. I am working on mac OS X (10.8.5) and the compiler is clang-503.0.40. Locale output is:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL="
```

and I have tried setting stty, but some funny characters creep into white spaces on the screen and in the files that I am writing my output to.

Example: `Ã¿Ã¿2,Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿1,12,21,Ã¿0,Ã¿2,Ã¿0.00,60.00,WinterDesignDay`

Whereas the expected output is:`2,          1,12,21,     0.00,60.00,WinterDesignDay`

I went through a lot of questions listed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding but I couldn't find an answer that solves my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. How are you displaying output? 2. Can you redirect/save output to a file, open the file in a hex editor and post hexadecimal byte values?

Comment: `50 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 20 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 2C`
`45 6E 65 72 67 79 50 6C 75 73 2C 20 56 65 72 73`
`69 6F 6E 20 38 2E 32 2E 30 2D 33 30 63 61 36 32`
`63 66 62 61 2C 20 59 4D 44 3D 32 2C 30 31 34 2E`
`31 30 2E 30 33 20 31 34 3A 31 33 0A FF FF 31 2C` is the hexadecimal output of `Program Version,EnergyPlus, Version 8.2.0-30ca62cfba, YMD=2,014.10.03 14:13
ˇˇ1,` --> notice the carrots...

Comment: Can I get the same, but for that WinterDesignDay line? Here there is too little data to figure out what's actually going on. And what program is actually displaying this output on the screen?

Comment: Following is the output of WinterDesignDay: `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 31 2C 31 32 2C 32
31 2C FF 30 2C FF 31 2C FF 30 2E 30 30 2C 36 30
2E 30 30 2C 57 69 6E 74 65 72 44 65 73 69 67 6E
44 61 79 0A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 36
2C 2D 31 35 2E 35 0A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF 34 30 2C 30 2E 30 0A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF 36 37 2C 2D 31 38 2E 32 30 38 36 35 35 32
31 31 34 32 30 37 0A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF` White space is basically `FF`

Comment: You are using a weird mix of UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 and MacRoman encodings. `FF` is whitespace in ISO, `ˇ` in MacRoman, and invalid in UTF-8.

Comment: @Karol, you are right. I am using eclipse (Helios) for my project and I followed the instructions given at stackoverflow:   `[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707986/eclipse-encoding-macroman-utf8)`.  I changed the text file encoding to UTF-8 in General->Workspace and also changed the encoding of the resource using the properties option. Resource now shows `inherited from container (UTF-8)`. But the problem still persists.

Comment: There is still the issue of encoding in editors and terminal emulators you use to display the output. Apart from those, I have no other ideas.